# Помогите, пожалуйста, выловить скрипт с ошибкой из стека вызовов javascript (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

В каком-то из скриптов допустил ошибку и теперь в консоль вываливается стек вызова из которого я никак не могу понять, какая именно из моих функций является инициатором ошибки.Вот сам стек:

```
(node:6587) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at MySQLQueryGenerator._whereParseSingleValueObject (/var/project/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2352:19)
at MySQLQueryGenerator.whereItemQuery (/var/project/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2139:21)
at /var/project/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2044:25
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at MySQLQueryGenerator.whereItemsQuery (/var/project/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2042:35)
at MySQLQueryGenerator.getWhereConditions (/var/project/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2444:19)
at MySQLQueryGenerator.selectQuery (/var/project/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1275:28)
at QueryInterface.select (/var/project/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:1104:27)
at /var/project/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1751:34
at tryCatcher (/var/project/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/project/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/var/project/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/project/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/var/project/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
at _drainQueueStep (/var/project/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
at _drainQueue (/var/project/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
at Async._drainQueues (/var/project/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/project/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

(node:6587) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 14)

Comment: В ошибке написано, что вы не отловили reject с помощью catch, который вернул ваш Promise, я предполагаю, что дело в том, что вы работаете с вашим промисом как с синхронным кодом, что в корне неправильно, или используйте async/await для асинхронного кода. Ну это я предполагаю, чтобы дать ответ на ваш вопрос приведете ваш код в том месте где возникает ошибка.

Comment: Да я уже понял, что дал маху и надо ловить исключение, но вот вопрос где? Из стека ничего непонятно, а контроллеров уже набралось прилично. Это точно мой бэкэнд и точно контроллер, но я во всех них использую Sequelize, который тут психует